# How do I make a program repeat itself after it catches an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I want the program to repeat itself after it gets a format exception.

Instead it just continues. How do I make it repeat?

For example it should print the error message after an exception and then repeat the program till the user complies.

I tried to put the try catch inside the do while loop but it make my numAge var local and showed an error.

```cs
int numAge;

try
{
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
        numAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine ());
    } while (numAge < 0);
}
catch (FormatException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine(err.Messagec + "Please try again");
    //how do I actually make it try again?
}

Console.WriteLine("Program continues");
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for flow control. In this specific case, you should use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, so that you can prevent an exception from ever occurring in the first place.

Comment: won't that only work for formatexception? What if I have an overflow exception is there a way to repeat a program after an exception?

Comment: @bubblepop It will work for any exception related to parsing including overflows, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Just move the try-catch block inside the loop instead of outside it:

```
do {
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
        numAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (FormatException err)
    {
        numAge = -1;
        Console.WriteLine(err.Messagec+ "Please try again");
    }
} while (numAge < 0);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, can you please tell me why you did numAge = -1?

Comment: @bubblepop just to be sure it's smaller than `0`, so the loop with continue looping.

Comment: how would I use that with multiple exceptions? I tried to use an indexoutofbounds exception and it didn't work

Comment: @bubblepop why would you have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` there?

Comment: oh sorry I meant an overflow exception. As soon as I put one it says "use of unassigned local variable." I just want it to repeat with multiple exceptions till the user gets it right.